# Is it possible to operate on each List from a grouping by collector without an intermediate map being created?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code that does a group by on a List, and then operates on each grouped List in turn converting it to a single item:

```
Map<Integer, List<Record>> recordsGroupedById = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.get("complex_id")));

List<Complex> whatIwant = recordsGroupedById.values().stream().map(this::toComplex)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `toComplex` function looks like:

```
Complex toComplex(List<Record> records);
```

I have the feeling I can do this without creating the intermediate map, perhaps using reduce.  Any ideas?

The input stream is ordered with the elements I want grouped sequentially in the stream.  Within a normal loop construct I'd be able to determine when the next group starts and create a "Complex" at that time.

Comment: You need to put the intermediate lists _somewhere_. Why not a `Map`? Otherwise, if you can build your `Complex` incrementally you could collect into a `Map<Integer, Complex>` with a custom collector.

Comment: Reduce doesn't look like an option as it always reduces a stream to zero or 1 element.  A custom collector that takes advantage of a sorted, sequential stream would be possible, but I have the feeling it will be a lot bigger than a simple for loop...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can avoid `Map` (honestly!) and do everything in single pipeline using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```
List<Complex> result = StreamEx.of(myList)
        .sortedBy(r -> r.get("complex_id"))
        .groupRuns((r1, r2) -> r1.get("complex_id").equals(r2.get("complex_id")))
        .map(this::toComplex)
        .toList();
```

Here we first sort input by `complex_id`, then use [`groupRuns`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#groupRuns-java.util.function.BiPredicate-) custom intermediate operation which groups adjacent stream element to the `List` if the given `BiPredicate` applied to two adjacent elements returns true. Then you have a stream of lists which is mapped to stream of `Complex` objects and finally collected to the list.

There are actually no intermediate maps and `groupRuns` is actually lazy (in sequential mode it keeps no more than one intermediate `List` at a time), it also parallelizes well. On the other hand my tests show that for unsorted input such solution is *slower* than `groupingBy`-based as it involves sorting the whole input. And of course `sortedBy` (which is just a shortcut for `sorted(Comparator.comparing(...))`) takes intermediate memory to store the input. If your input is already sorted (or at least partially sorted, so TimSort can perform fast), then such solution usually faster than `groupingBy`.

Comment: I see potential for another convenience method, to allow `groupRuns` with a property function, implying equality test, analogous to `Comparator.comparing` for sort operations. Unfortunately, `BiPredicate` has no such factory methods.

Comment: Accepted this as it is the only solution that avoids a map -- I was hoping it be possible in Java 8 as I was a bit new to streams at the time :)

Answer (score 6):

Create a collector that combines groupingBy and your post-processing function with `collectingAndThen`.

```
Map<Integer, Complex> map = myList.stream()
    .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(r -> r.get("complex_id"), 
                               Xxx::toComplex));
```

If you just want a `Collection<Complex>` here, you can then ask the map for its `values()`.

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky The `toComplex()` function here takes a `List<Record>` and produces a `Complex`.  It doesn't have to deal with Stream.

Comment: This is messed up. The result of `groupingBy()` is Map, and post-processor must be able to take the return type of pre-collector. This should be that way: `myList.stream().collect(groupingBy(r -> r.get("complex_id"), collectingAndThen(toList(), this::toComplex)))`. You see, post-processor is there for downstream only, not for whole result.

Comment: this code requires several comment lines to explain what it actually does ;)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. You **must** collect all data to ensure the contents of all groups are known before moving foreward. Obviously, however, if you can perform processes on each element in the group as it is assigned to the group then that can be done.

Think about it this way - imagine the very first item in the list and the very last item in the list contain the same `complex_id`. You must then have to wait for the end of the list anyway to fully gather that group (and all the others) so you must gather all groups together before processing.

Also - you should obviously be able to do:

```
    List<Complex> whatIwant = myList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r.get("complex_id")))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(this::toComplex)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: As I mentioned above - depending on the logic the OP could turn this into a custom collector that build the `Complex` rather than `List<>`. But that would obviously require quite a bid of logic...

Comment: @Boris the Spider: the question was how to avoid the *map*, not how to avoid the *lists*.

Comment: That's just avoiding the assignment to a Map variable (I split it on purpose to make it more clear that I don't want the map being created).

Comment: @john16384 - The map (or some collector) is inevitable.

Comment: Obviously this only makes sense on a preordered stream, but it is quite legit